# how to save an blob in database - typeorm

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, typeorm

**Generaly**: 
can someone just give an example how to save a Blob object like in my example

> Blob {size:1996683, type: "image/png"}
>   size: 1996683 type: "image/png"
>   proto: Blob

in a cordova typeorm database (with the data content)? Inital if i get the Blob i can work with it fine and can display the image direclty without any converting or something else. but when loading it out of the database its just a string with the object type.. (see long version)

**Long version of my problem:**
im currently building an ionic app with cordova and angular. for the database im using the typeorm module.  which i initialize like this:

```
await createConnection({
    type: 'cordova',
    database: 'test.db',
    location: 'default',
    logging: false,
    synchronize: true,
    entities: [
      User,
      QrCode,
      QrFile,
      QrOrder,
      SubItem,
      Property,
  ]
})
```

my qrFile entity which contains the blob column looks like:

```
@Entity('qrfile')
export class QrFile{

...

  @Column("blob", { nullable: true })
  content: Blob;
```

Here i tried a lot of other types instead of Blob e.g. Buffer, ArrayBuffer and so on...

I added a few debug console logs in the "main" method which is managing the entity content:

```js
public async getFileContent(qrFile: QrFile) {
    if(!qrFile.content){
      console.log("getFileBase64Content -> no content so load from server")
      let result  = await this.loadContentFromServer(qrFile).catch(reject => {
        return null;
      });
      qrFile.content = result;//await new Response(result).arrayBuffer()//new Buffer(result);
      qrFile = await this.saveQrFileToDB(qrFile);
    }else{
      console.log("getFileBase64Content -> content found!")
    }
    console.log("IMPORTANT!!! content which will be used:")
    console.log(qrFile.content)

    return qrFile.content;
  }
```

Now i'm loading the file from a server as octet stream (so the first if check is true and i have to load and then set the content) the content is a real Blob the first time, when i loaded it from the server:

console output:

> IMPORTANT!!! content which will be used: main.js:6217
>   Blob {size:1996683, type: "image/png"}
>   size: 1996683 type: "image/png"
>   proto: Blob

but the second time this method is called i have something in the content of the qrFile but it isn't a Blob...

console output

> IMPORTANT!!! content which will be used: main.js:6217
>   [object Object]

**It's pretty strange, cause the saveToDB method is returning the "new/updated" entity and i ALWAYS use the content of that entity.**

Like i wrote i tried already a lot. like make different buffers out of the first Blob and set this as content. and then after loading out of the database convert the Buffer back to a Blob but nothing worked. i have always just the object Object with which a can't really work it seems like.

ionic info:

> cli packages: (C:\Users#####\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)
>
> ```
> @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.3
> ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.1
> ```
>
> global packages:
>
> ```
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
> ```
>
> local packages:
>
> ```
> @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
> Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
> Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
> ```
>
> System:
>
> ```
> Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
> Node              : v10.15.3
> npm               : 6.4.1
> OS                : Windows 10
> ```
>
> Environment Variables:
>
> ```
> ANDROID_HOME : D:\android_sdk
> ```
>
> Misc:
>
> ```
> backend : pro
> ```

And package.json entry for typeorm:

> "typeorm": "^0.2.5",

**Edit**:
i now activated the logging for typeORM and did some more console logs:
the update query is:

```
query: UPDATE "qrfile" SET "content" = ? WHERE "id" = ? -- PARAMETERS: [{"size":1996683,"type":"image/png"},1]
```

and a direct query after the save on the qrFile results in:

> content: "[object Object]"

so there is a simple String with just [object Object] saved in the db?!

so one more update from my side:
created an extra method which updates the content value directly via a query:
with this method i get as db select result "content: "[object Blob]" still a string it seems. also strange is that the parameter.
to be honest i don't really like to convert the image to base64 and save it as string or something like that. i mean the doc of typeorm (https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/entities.md) says that blob is a valid entity type - so it should work somehow.